# LAPS ms-Mcs-AdmPwd blank or null values

Tags: active-directory, powershell, password-management

I am writing a script to export all computer LAPS ms-Mcs-AdmPwd values to KeePass to allow historical logging.

I have a few machines for whatever reason a few objects have no password set.  However I am getting a value back.  It is not $null or "".

```
$LAPSPWD = Get-AdmPwdPassword ServerName
Write-Host $LAPSPWD.password

$LAPSPWD -eq $null
$LAPSPWD -eq ""
```

When running this I get two false responses.

How do I determine what is being returned, so I can make it an IF statement exception to handle further processing?

I get the same response if I use the LAPS PS module (Example Above) or Query the directory(Example Below)

```
$computer = Get-ADComputer -Identity ServerName -SearchBase $dn -Property name,ms-Mcs-AdmPwd,CanonicalName
$LAPSpwd= $computer.'ms-Mcs-AdmPwd'
```

To add to this I tried to Measure-Object, and all came back with ZERO

```
Measure-Object $LAPSPWD | measure -Line -Character -Word

Lines Words Characters Property
----- ----- ---------- --------
    0     0          0
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not add an LDAP query filter `ms-Mcs-AdmPwd=*`?

Comment: @GregAskew I think it does not matter, both the commands I used are going back to the same LDAP source.  Thoughts?

Comment: Thoughts? If the query is only for objects that have a value for ms-Mcs-AdmPwd this should be unnecessary.